# Set margin of a scrollview

Tags: java, android, layout, scrollview, android-framelayout

I am trying to use a scrollview in a framelayout.
The scrollview should be displayed just in the downer half of the display.

At the moment the positioning is right:

http://www.gtv-handball.de/Unbenannt.png

As you can see, the right areas are scollable or not.
But the problem is, that the upper part can't be clicked anymore, cause the scrollview is over this part.

To display the scrollview in the downer half, I put some padding on it:

```
scrollviwe = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.linlayout);
scrollview.setPadding(0, 175, 0, 0);
```

So I didn't find any way to get this displayed with the padding option.

**I think, there is no way to get around setting a margin for the scrollview,
but how do I so?**

Here is the complete, but shortened XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left" >
         <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/coverimg"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="top|left"
         android:maxHeight="100dp"
         android:minHeight="130dp"
         android:minWidth="130dp"
         android:src="@drawable/cover_img" />
</FrameLayout>
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/linlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linlayout2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/teilen"
    style="ButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Teilen"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/kaufen"
    style="ButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Kaufen"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/youtube"
    style="ButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="YouTube"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Zuletzt gehört:" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: if you put the scrollview on top of the other framelayout, it won't work for sure. use a linearlayout (vertical) and put each with a height of 0dp and a weight of 1

Comment: where should i put the linearlayout? after the first framelayout and before the scrollview?

Comment: instead of the first framelayout

Comment: then I am not able to manage overlapping some views.

Comment: didn't realize they were overlapping. use a relative layout, then

Comment: okay, i used relative layout. nearly everything is working, but the scrollview is not fully displayed. it is longer than the display, I can scroll a bit, but i can not see everything, what is in the scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking into using a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)?  If I understand your goals correctly, it might be easier to manage all the different views on the screen, as you can align views relative to each other or the borders of the screen.  It can also be used in a similar fashion to FrameLayouts to overlay views on top of one another.

Comment: I tried, but I ended up using a framelayout. I had some difficulties in positioning the different views in relativelayouts...

Comment: I changed the layout to a relativelayout. Everything is working. Thanks Aaron.

Comment: Great!  Glad you were able to get it working.  RelativeLayouts can be tricky sometimes, but they do help keep the code more trim.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you wrap a linear layout. Since its easier to manage how much space it takes on the screen using weights.

you can try this out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/framelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="top|left"
android:layout_weight="0.5" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/coverimg"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:minHeight="130dp"
    android:minWidth="130dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Text"/>
    <!-- Add other views -->
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/linlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.5" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linlayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/teilen"
            style="ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Teilen" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/kaufen"
            style="ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Kaufen" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/youtube"
            style="ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="YouTube" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Zuletzt gehört:" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Problem is, that I am setting up some margin programmatically like this: FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
  FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, width/2);
  fl.setLayoutParams(lp);
I am getting 09-18 14:16:29.665: E/AndroidRuntime(772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 14:16:29.665: E/AndroidRuntime(772): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: For which components do you set the params.

Comment: All components in the framelayout.

Comment: In the answer that i have suggested, there is only one component, namely the imageview within the framelayout. should i assume that you are applying new parameters values only for this component. Could you also throw some light on what you are planning to achieve by changing the parameters programatically.

Comment: I am achieving the same layouts on different types and sizes of displays. Is it better to put all these views, you can see them in the picture I've posted, in a relativelayout?

Comment: The XML you posted did not contain any-other views than the imageview. If you are looking to achieve some thing linke in the pic then might i suggest that you can do something like what i have done in my edit. You can get different widths/height by adjusting the weight which will automatically adapt to different screen sizes/resolutions.

Comment: Okay, I changed everything to a relative layout. The layout is exactly as it is in the image, and i can scroll the scrollview. But the scrollview is not fully displayed. I can scroll a bit, but I dont see all content in the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting margin or padding to the View outside the ScrollView. In this case it would be FrameLayout.